# Python Creating and Appending Rows After Comparing Two Columns in my Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, compare

I have a DataFrame where I am looking at delivery orders for a varying amount of products in a date range. Specifically Tuesdays and Thursdays. Here is a Sample: df

| Product_and_Size | Week | Sample | Day | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1050-5.0 | 6 | 11 | Tuesday | 2021-10-05 | 2 |
| 1052-55.0 | 8 | 15 | Tuesday | 2021-10-19 | 1 |
| 1052-T-55.0 | 8 | 15 | Tuesday | 2021-10-19 | 1 |
| 1252-5.0 | 1 | 1 | Tuesday | 2021-08-31 | 8 |
| 1252-5.0 | 2 | 3 | Thursday | 2021-09-02 | 6 |

I want to create a forecast based on my 2 month time range for each individual product. But some products don't show up on some or almost all of the dates in the range I am looking at because they were only bought once. But I would still like a forecast that says in like 2 months 1 of 1050-5.0 was bought. This way Production can make sure to have it in stock on the off chance it will be bought.

My problem is my Dataframe has only one observation of 1050-5.0 for Tuesday 2021-10-05 , but no observations at all for the other dates in my dataframe. so I wouldn't be able to get a histogram because it has one datapoint. So I want to iterate through the dataframe, and if the product doesn't have an observation for a date in my date range, I want it to create a new row where it retains the dates week and day information, but adds 0 for the amount.

I tried creating a loop but it didn't work and I deleted what I tried. right now I just have a loop trying to compare and see if it gives me anything.

```
for x in df.iterrows():
    if df['Product_and-Size'] != df['Date'].unique():
        print(df['Product_and-Size'], df['Date'])
```

but I get and error because the lengths are different.
Can someone show me how I would compare and then how I would append a new row with the same information for the date but a value of 0?

My Dates:
Dates

2021-08-31 2021-09-02 2021-09-07 2021-09-09 2021-09-14 2021-09-16 2021-09-21 2021-09-23 2021-09-28 2021-09-30 2021-10-05 2021-10-07 2021-10-12 2021-10-14 2021-10-19 2021-10-21 2021-10-26

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are asking. If you provide an expected output, it'd more helpful.

This may not be what you want, but you can `reindex()` via `groupby()` using the dates provided. This will add those dates to each product, but you'll need to go in add the dates, week and day information as that seems dependent on the date and not the product.

You'll need `import io` to create the dataframe in this example.

```
data='''Product_and_Size    Week    Sample  Day Date    Amount
1050-5.0    6   11  Tuesday 2021-10-05  2
1052-55.0   8   15  Tuesday 2021-10-19  1
1052-T-55.0 8   15  Tuesday 2021-10-19  1
1252-5.0    1   1   Tuesday 2021-08-31  8
1252-5.0    2   3   Thursday    2021-09-02  6'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' \s+', engine='python')

df.set_index('Date', drop=True, inplace=True)

           Product_and_Size  Week  Sample       Day  Amount
Date
2021-10-05         1050-5.0     6      11   Tuesday       2
2021-10-19        1052-55.0     8      15   Tuesday       1
2021-10-19      1052-T-55.0     8      15   Tuesday       1
2021-08-31         1252-5.0     1       1   Tuesday       8
2021-09-02         1252-5.0     2       3  Thursday       6
    
mydates = ['2021-08-31', '2021-09-02', '2021-09-07', '2021-09-09', '2021-09-14',
'2021-09-16', '2021-09-21', '2021-09-23', '2021-09-28', '2021-09-30',
'2021-10-05', '2021-10-07', '2021-10-12', '2021-10-14',
'2021-10-19', '2021-10-21', '2021-10-26']


# I use apply() here, and send the groups to a function. You could use lambda instead, however if you want to to more to the groups before returning the reindexed group, then a function is cleaner, IMHO.

def reindex_groups(x):
    x = x.reindex(mydates).fillna(0)
    return x


dfn = df.groupby('Product_and_Size').apply(reindex_groups)
dfn.drop('Product_and_Size', axis=1, inplace=True)
dfn.reset_index(inplace=True)


   Product_and_Size        Date  Week  Sample Day  Amount
0          1050-5.0  2021-08-31 0.000   0.000   0   0.000
1          1050-5.0  2021-09-02 0.000   0.000   0   0.000
2          1050-5.0  2021-09-07 0.000   0.000   0   0.000
3          1050-5.0  2021-09-09 0.000   0.000   0   0.000
4          1050-5.0  2021-09-14 0.000   0.000   0   0.000
..              ...         ...   ...     ...  ..     ...
63         1252-5.0  2021-10-12 0.000   0.000   0   0.000
64         1252-5.0  2021-10-14 0.000   0.000   0   0.000
65         1252-5.0  2021-10-19 0.000   0.000   0   0.000
66         1252-5.0  2021-10-21 0.000   0.000   0   0.000
67         1252-5.0  2021-10-26 0.000   0.000   0   0.000

[68 rows x 6 columns]

dfn[dfn['Amount']>0]

   Product_and_Size        Date  Week  Sample       Day  Amount
10         1050-5.0  2021-10-05 6.000  11.000   Tuesday   2.000
31        1052-55.0  2021-10-19 8.000  15.000   Tuesday   1.000
48      1052-T-55.0  2021-10-19 8.000  15.000   Tuesday   1.000
51         1252-5.0  2021-08-31 1.000   1.000   Tuesday   8.000
52         1252-5.0  2021-09-02 2.000   3.000  Thursday   6.000
```

The dataframe grows considerably as it adds a new date range for each product.

The last line just shows a filtered dataframe the same as the input, meaning you've retained all the information and now you have zeros for all your other dates.

Comment: I think this is doing exactly what I was wanting. My only problem is when I run this I get an error saying: ValueError: Cannot set non-string value '0' into a StringArray. My 'Product_and_size' I have as an object type

Comment: which line is giving you the error? are you setting the date to index as shown? 'Product_and_size' being an object is an issue, or at least shouldn't  be unless you data doesn't fit the same patterns.

Comment: I indexed my DataFrame with the dates. My Dates I have created a list from by doing this

Comment: `Unique_Dates = [df['Date'].unique()]` I then followed the code you provided ` df.set_index('Date', drop=True, inplace=True)
def reindex_groups(x):
    x = x.reindex(Unique_Dates).fillna(0)
    return x
dfn = df.groupby('Product_and_Size').apply(reindex_groups)
dfn.drop('Product_and_Size', axis=1, inplace=True)
dfn.reset_index(inplace=True) `   This is the error I get when I try to run the code: 
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\spyder\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\string_.py", line 406, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError(ValueError: Cannot set non-string value '0' into a StringArray.

Comment: I’m going to say unique_dates isn’t the same as mydates. Yours may be a list of datetime not strings. But again, this debugging is difficult so just be sure at each step of my code your code produces the exact same objects and data types.

Comment: I see my problem with this now. I have duplicate dates in my index, so I cannot reindex. I showed you a sample data set where there was no duplicate dates, however my real data set has 100's of values and any duplicate dates in my dates column.